# Favorite Tags buttons need more padding

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, design, tag-watching

If you have a single-letter favourite tag, e.g. [c](/questions/tagged/c), then the red "X" to remove the tag is much bigger than the tag name. I often accidentally remove the tag when I only intended to click on it.

Can you add some extra padding, or perhaps a minimum tag width, please?

Comment: Maybe. But I really don't want those tags to be any bigger. They already take up *enough* room on my homepage. Especially the "ignored" tags. In fact, I'm not sure why they're visible all the time... That list goes on for miles.

Comment: Perhaps remove the delete X in the list, and provide that functionality in the page it links to? Or add a confirmation dialogue.