# Aren't tag buttons too short?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favorite Tags buttons need more padding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91478/favorite-tags-buttons-need-more-padding)

Short tag buttons, those consisting of a single letter (ie: `C`) are so small that when I try to click one I risk to click on the closing `x`, which is annoying.

[image: c tag]

The entire button width is, for the `C` example, 0.82cm (0.32 inches) wide, but the clickable area, if you want to avoid to click the `x`, is only 0.34cm (0.14 inches) wide.

Maybe I'm getting too old, but please make those buttons wider.