# Unintended deletion of favourite tags

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [option to lock “interesting tags” section so 'x' isn't hit accidentally on a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350/option-to-lock-interesting-tags-section-so-x-isnt-hit-accidentally-on-a-tag)
>   [Favorite Tags buttons need more padding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91478/favorite-tags-buttons-need-more-padding)

It does often happen to me that I delete one of my favourite tags unintentionally, especially when the actual tag contains up to three letters like: c, c#, css, etc., you can tell easily that I am not a 3d shooter person, but tag-based navigation could definitely be amended.
As deletion is rare in comparison to displaying all the question with the particular tag maybe we should have some sort of a timer, say 500ms on mousehover event for displaying the deletion prompt or anything else that could make favourite tags less prone to unintended deletion.

Comment: rather because it happens a lot and I really like SO

Comment: It happens.  But, I usually am able to add the tags right back in.  They're out of order for a bit, but they're still there...